# Passing files selected in project views to external tools

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

Is it possible to pass paths to all files currently selected in the project view to an external tool?

I know you can use the `$FilePath$` macro but it only seems to pass the path to the first selected file ignoring the rest and no other macro seems suitable. A workaround would also be using all the files from the parent directory, but that's not feasible in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible right now, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97869).

Comment: I just did - this feature would really be useful for my team. Thanks for the quick response!